# Why is my very first Google Drive REST API request always so slow?

Tags: c#, rest, google-drive-api

The program I'm writing retrieves information from 3 different files in my Google Drive folder using the exact same code, but the first file always takes a long time to get the file data (about 30s+) but the next two files get the information almost instantly.  Why is there always such a delay with the very first API request?

I currently only have these three 5mb files in my Google Drive storage so it's not like it's looking through hundreds of files.

This is a condensed console app version of the code I'm using that just gets a bit of info about an xml file in my Drive folder:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Drive_Console_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        public static DriveService DriveService;
        private static string fileId;
        private static string fileDescription;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Drive");
        ConnectToGoogleDrive();
        GetCloudFileProperties("Chris.xml");

        Console.WriteLine("Finding file");
        Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + fileId);
        Console.WriteLine("File Description: " + fileDescription);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void ConnectToGoogleDrive()
    {
        string filename = "media_vault_credentials.json";
        string cSecret = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, filename);
        DriveService = OAuth2Authorization.GetDriveService(cSecret, "user", new[]
            { Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService.Scope.Drive });
    }

    public static void GetCloudFileProperties(string fileName)
    {
        string pageToken = null;
        do
        {
            var request = DriveService.Files.List();
            request.Q = "mimeType='" + GetMimeType(fileName) + "'" + " and trashed=false";
            request.Spaces = "drive";
            request.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, description, properties)";
            request.PageToken = pageToken;
            var result = request.Execute();

            foreach (var file in result.Files)
            {
                if (file.Name == fileName)
                {
                    fileId = file.Id;
                    fileDescription = file.Description;
                }
            }

            pageToken = result.NextPageToken;
        } while (pageToken != null);
    }

    private static string GetMimeType(string fileName)
    {
        string mimeType = "application/unknown";
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
        if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
            mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
        return mimeType;
    }
}


public static class OAuth2Authorization
{
    public static DriveService GetDriveService(string clientSecretJson, string userName, string[] scopes)
    {

        var cred = GetUserCredential(clientSecretJson, userName, scopes);
        return GetService(cred);
    }

    private static UserCredential GetUserCredential(string clientSecretJson, string userName, string[] scopes)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretJson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);

            var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                                                     scopes,
                                                                     userName,
                                                                     CancellationToken.None,
                                                                     new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

            credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
            return credential;
        }
    }

    private static DriveService GetService(UserCredential credential)
    {
        return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Media Vault"
        });
    }


}
```

}

Here is what I see on Fiddler:

[image: Fiddler results while app is running]

Comment: 30 seconds is a *very* long time - that surprises me. The first request may well be fetching an auth token, but it's odd if that takes 30 seconds. I suggest you use Fiddler to look at which request is actually taking the time. It's *possible* that the Drive API is slow for the first request, but then caches a lot of data...

Comment: Its going to depend largely on the size of the file and which server you hit and if anyone else is running anything on the server at the same time.

Comment: Are you testing this from VisualStudio or from IIS deployment?

Comment: @Matt This is in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: As @JonSkeet said, take a look with the Fiddler and see what takes so long. My guess is also that there is some caching running. If you can try to deploy the API to IIS, I bet the same will happen the first time and then the API should continue to work normally.

Comment: The first request may be just the cost of spinning up IIS. I'd suggest adding an unrelated route to IIS (that does as little as possible) so that you can separate the IIS startup cost from the execution cost.

Comment: I haven't used IIS before so I'll have to try and learn how to use it.  In the mean time I've added the extra code I use to set up my connection to Drive in case there are any obvious problems there.  @DalmTo I think I that will be more familiar to you as I believe it was based on some of your Drive API code.

Comment: The delay has decided not to happen at all this afternoon so I'll have to wait and post more info when it starts happening again.  Thanks.

Comment: @JonSkeet OK I've downloaded Fiddler and run my app, though I'm not really sure what I'm looking for.  I've added some screen grabs of the three results that pop up during the big delay I mentioned.  Does any of this help?  Thanks.

Comment: It's definitely becoming more useful - but it's slightly confusing because you've got Firefox in there as well. At this point I'd write a small *console* app which just makes the requests. I'd also personally **temporarily** turn on HTTPS decryption in Fiddler, so you can see the exact requests and responses. (Fiddler installs a local HTTPS certificate so it can run a man-in-the-middle attack, effectively. You'd want to remove that certificate after the diagnostics.) It does look very odd that in the first request it looks like it takes over 20 seconds just to get the server connected.

Comment: @JonSkeet I turned on HTTPS decryption and ran it again.  I've replaced  the first Fiddler image with the results.  There are a lot more results, so please let me know if you want screen grabs of any specific item (and which Fiddler tab).

Comment: @ChrisUK: It's probably worth just customizing the columns - that'll give lots of information. If you right-click on the headers, you can customize the columns, and the ones you're interested in are in the "Session Timers" collection. It would be good to see Server_ThinkTime, Overall_Elapsed, ClientConnected, ServerConnected, TCP/IP Connect and HTTPSHandshake. The cache and content-type columns aren't terribly important. You may need to expand the headers in order to make sure the values are fully visible.

Comment: If you have a tiny console app you're using to test, you could post that too so that I could try the same thing myself. It would also be interesting to know what your network setup is - are you behind a proxy? Have you tried the same code in other network contexts? Hopefully we'll make progress - thanks very much for being responsive to my queries :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Regarding a small app, I'll try and come up with something that causes the delay AND is small enough to send you later today.  I'm not behind a proxy, and no I haven't tried on another network.  I've uploaded a new screen grab with the recommended columns.  And thank YOU for being willing to help - I'm way out of my depth with this stuff!

Comment: @JonSkeet I created a console test app, but at the moment the long delay has stopped happening again even with my full program, so I don't know if the test app will even replicate the issue until it starts happening again.  Anything suspicious in the screen grab I took earlier?  Also, any idea why sometimes the problem goes away by itself?  Strange!  Thanks Jon :-)

Comment: The 21 second connection time in the first two rows definitely looks suspicious. I'd expect it to be really quick. Without knowing what's causing the problem, I can't really speculate about why it only happens sometimes - but I'd suggest maybe waiting until the failure repeats in your real app, and then run the test app.

Comment: @JonSkeet The delay started happening again this morning, and it happens with the console test app I put together yesterday (I edited my original post to show this in full so that you can try it).  It uses the following NuGet packages: Google.Apis, Google.Apis.Auth, Google.Apis.Core, Google.Apis.Drive.v3, and Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: @ChrisUK: Okay, that's useful. I would suggest removing the old screenshots from Fiddler, and updating the post to screenshots taken from Fiddler just when running the sample code - otherwise there's a disconnect between the two that isn't obvious unless you've been following very closely. (I'd also suggest that the sample could be simplified a lot by removing the "try/catch/throw new exception" - just let exceptions propagate and you'll end up with simpler code *and* more information due to better stack traces)

Comment: @JonSkeet I've made the suggested changes.  Let me know if there are any specific screen grabs you want me to add.  If you can figure this out you're a legend! :-)

Comment: Okay, it *definitely* looks like it's a network problem - if you look at the trace, you can see there's a 20 second TCP-IP connection time even to sqm.telemetry.microsoft.com. So I don't think this is a problem with your code or our client library code. It's *possible* that there's something within the .NET Core HTTP libraries that's causing the issue... but it's hard to tell. I'd probably next try to reproduce the problem without involving .NET at all. For example, if you run `ping www.googleapis.com` from the command line, does that show any issues?

Comment: Yeah I get "Request timed out" 4 times in a row when pinging.  That doesn't sound good...

Comment: I used ping 8.8.8.8 for Google's public DNS and it worked OK.  Apparently this means I have a DNS fault?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario: when I try to write a document in Firestore (using Google.Cloud.Firestore C# SDK) or try to generate an access token (using Google.Apis.Auth C# SDK), I get 50 seconds (or more) of delay.

Changing the DNS address of my connection from 8.8.8.8 to any other, the slowness goes away.